# How is the /proc/pid/fd/0, 1, 2 is linked to tty device?

Tags: stdio, tty

Linux process link stdin/output/err to /dev/tty, for example:

```
ls -all /proc/5310/fd show
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Mar 31 09:58 0 -> /dev/pts/1    
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Mar 31 09:58 1 -> /dev/pts/1    
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Mar 31 09:58 2 -> /dev/pts/1
```

Which component in system is in charge of the link? How it link the fd 0/1/2 to /dev/pts/1? How can I change it to be /dev/pts/2